# How to access an index of a string in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, plsql

I have a program say

```
DECLARE
str VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
str:='Test';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(// Here I want to print a character of any index from string//);
END;
/
```

How to do it?

Comment: yeah! edited. Any answer if you have? @Gordon

Comment: Please elaborate on what **exactly** do you understand under the term "a character of any index from a string". Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27346622/edit) link below your question and post a few examples of inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: check answer, you will get.

Comment: Ah, I see you needed not only Oracle but also an oracle. ;-) OK, enjoy. :-)

Comment: land per char behen k loray @nop77svk :D

Comment: Nuž, tiež by som ti tu mohol písať kdejaké bludy v mojej materčine, ale kam by to viedlo, že? :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd use the [SUBSTR function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions169.htm#SQLRF06114). For example:

```
DECLARE
  str VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  str:='Test';

  FOR i IN 1..LENGTH(str) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Character at index ' || i || ' is ' || SUBSTR(str, i, 1));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to find a particular character and its index within a string, also look at the Oracle function INSTR().

INSTR( string, substring [, start_position [,  nth_appearance ] ] )

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Hey don't forget [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm#SQLRF06303)!

```
DECLARE
  str VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  str:='Test';

  FOR i IN 1..LENGTH(str) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Character at index ' || i || ' is ' || REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '.', i));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

The dot matches any character.